# Why does setting a default value on an enum dependency property fail in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, dependency-properties, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to use an enum as the type of a dependency property, but any setting of the default seems to fail.

The compilation succeeds, but when I try to use the object in XAML I get a "Specified Cast is not Valid" error and the blue underline on my object.

VS2012 using WinRT.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I am using :

```
public class WheelPanel : Panel
{
    public enum ItemAlignmentOptions
    {
        Left, Center, Right
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="ItemAlignment" /> dependency property.
    /// </summary>

    // This fails using null

    //public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    //    ItemAlignmentPropertyName,
    //    typeof(ItemAlignmentOptions),
    //    typeof(WheelPanel),
    //    new PropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(ItemAlignmentChanged)));

    // This fails using a default value

    //public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    //    ItemAlignmentPropertyName,
    //    typeof(ItemAlignmentOptions),
    //    typeof(WheelPanel),
    //    new PropertyMetadata(ItemAlignmentOptions.Center,new PropertyChangedCallback(ItemAlignmentChanged)));

    // This works!
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        ItemAlignmentPropertyName,
        typeof(ItemAlignmentOptions),
        typeof(WheelPanel),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ItemAlignmentChanged)));

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="ItemAlignment" /> dependency property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string ItemAlignmentPropertyName = "ItemAlignment";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value of the <see cref="ItemAlignment" />
    /// property. This is a dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public ItemAlignmentOptions ItemAlignment
    {
        get { return (ItemAlignmentOptions)GetValue(ItemAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using '1' as the value. The underlying type of an enum is Int32 (by default), maybe it expects an integer number as the default.

Comment: That appears to work.  

FWIW - I get a brief com error when I change from a default to a non-default value in XAML, but it goes away when I then compile.  Might be related, might not.